# How to add custom data in a story board?

Tags: rally

Question 1: Is it possible to add custom data (Ex: testcase count : 5) to each card in a story board? If so, how? I couldn't find an example or specific information in documentation.

Question 2: Is it possible to get testcase count (including child story testcases)for a highlevel story in one query?

Please let me know. Here's my code

```
Ext.define('Rally.Story.View', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',

    launch: function() {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Filter by Target Release:',
            model: 'UserStory',
            field: 'c_TargetRelease',
            value: '15.0',
            listeners: {
                select: this._onSelect,
                ready: this._onLoad,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },

    _onLoad: function() {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
            types: ['User Story'],
            attribute: 'ScheduleState',
            readOnly: true,
            fetch: ['Name', 'TestCases', 'c_StoryType', 'c_TargetRelease', 'PlanEstimate', 'Priority', 'TaskEstimateTotal', 'TaskRemainingTotal'],
            context: this.getContext(),
            cardConfig: {
                editable: false,
                showIconsAndHighlightBorder: false,
                fields: ['Name', 'c_StoryType', 'c_TargetRelease', 'PlanEstimate', 'c_PriorityBin', 'Parent', 'TestCases', 'TaskEstimateTotal', 'TaskRemainingTotal']
            },
            storeConfig: {
                filters: [
                    {
                        property: 'c_StoryType',
                        value: 'SAGA Feature'
                    },
                    {
                        property: 'c_TargetRelease',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: this.down('rallyfieldvaluecombobox').getValue()
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    },

    _onSelect: function() {
        var board = this.down('rallycardboard');
        board.refresh({
            storeConfig: {
                filters: [
                    {
                        property: 'c_StoryType',
                        value: 'SAGA Feature'
                    },
                    {
                        property: 'c_TargetRelease',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: this.down('rallyfieldvaluecombobox').getValue()
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    },           
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample card I made that contains the test case count:

[image: Card Screenshot]

You can add a field by simply including an object with some rendering information in it instead of just a simple string in the fields array in the cardConfig:

```
cardConfig: {
    fields: [
        'Name', //simple string field to show
        {
            name: 'TCCount', //field name
            hasValue: function() {return true;}, //always show this field
            renderTpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.LabeledFieldTemplate', {
                        fieldLabel: 'Test Case Count', //the field label
                        valueTemplate: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
                            ['{[this.getTestCaseCount(values)]}',
                             {getTestCaseCount: function(data) { return data.Summary.TestCases.Count;}}])
                    })
        },
        //additional string fields
        'PlanEstimate', 'Parent', 'TestCases', 'TaskEstimateTotal', 'TaskRemainingTotal']
}
```

This ended up being less straightforward than I thought it might be, but at least it is doable.  The key part is using the LabeledFieldTemplate, specifying a field label and a value template to actually render the content.

You'll also notice the little beaker status icon in the footer which is automatically rendered because TestCases was included in the fields list.

As for your second question there is no roll up field on story for the total number of test cases included on child stories.

Comment: Thank you so much Kyle. This is very helpful!